# How do i use installed python modules

Tags: python

I installed a module package (playsound) and I've been stuck trying to use it, I have tried opening the package from cmd but nothing worked , I dont know how to use this package , please help .
edit : I have tried suggested awnsers but it didint work , here is a screenshot maybe im doing something wrong https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCORU.jpg

Comment: Do you have an idle? Try doing "import playsound" to import the package in the code and here is a guide: https://pythonbasics.org/python-play-sound/

Comment: I recommend following a python tutorial(such as the [official one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial)) before you attempt to use any modules as you will have a hard time using them without properly learning python.

Comment: @rovvan, man I don't see any error that your snippet throws, so I believe that the code is importing the library properly! (Otherwise, line 2 playsound () wouldn't have worked). Check the hardware config once!

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way of downloading modules is through [Pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)

Pip is already installed when you install Python.

You can download [playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) using this command in cmd:

```
pip install playsound
```

Now import the function from the module:

```py
from playsound import playsound
```

Then you can call the `playfound` function with this:

```py
playsound('/path/to/a/sound/file/you/want/to/play.mp3')
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested but there is no sound playing

Comment: like in this photo https://imgur.com/a/Zz5fR04 am i doing something wrong  ?